# Foxpro replace with "" not in

Tags: foxpro

I hereby seek for a solution. I have one dbf for january and february each. There are two columns named A and B in each dbf, A is a series of number and B is vlookup, and I want to replace the columnB in february with "new" if its values in columnA do not appear in the column A in january, and "old" for vice versa. My code is the following:

```
REPLACE ALL B WITH "Old"
REPLACE ALL B WITH "New" FOR A NOT IN (sele A FROM &filejanuary)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above commentator was close.
Using SQL UPDATE Commands...

```
* --- Replace ALL Feb.B with "Old" ---
UPDATE February SET February.B = 'Old'

* --- Now change Feb.B to "New" for Applicable Conditions ---
UPDATE February SET February.B = 'New' ;
  WHERE February.A NOT IN (SELECT A FROM January)
```

NOTE - there is also a VFP Command approach

```
* --- Replace ALL Feb.B with "Old" ---
SELECT February
REPLACE ALL February.B WITH "Old"

* --- Relate table January to table February through Field A ---
SELECT January
SET ORDER TO A   && Assumes Index built on Jan with Expression = A

SELECT February
SET RELATION TO A INTO January
* --- Replace ALL Feb.B with "New" for No Related A in Jan ---
REPLACE ALL B WITH "New" FOR EMPTY(January.A)
```

Good Luck

Comment: Yes i have completed it using @Dhugalma 's command. Thanks to both.

Comment: When you say "The above commentator was close.", what did you mean exactly? What part didn't work for you? You can do the same thing using many different forms in SQL and also in VFP. @AngYiwei, It was not close but right on target. You shouldn't decide with assumptions and try first. AND BTW, that "close" code even works in VFP5.

Answer (score 0):

```
update February set February.B = 'Old'
update February set February.B = 'New' ;
   where not exists (select * from January where January.A = February.A)
```

Comment: i think the command could be used for other SQL language but not directly in FoxPro

Comment: That code is also valid for fox pro. When saying fox pro, which version are you talking about?

Comment: sorry for late replying, I am currently using VFP7.0

Comment: and that code is also valid for VFP7. Wish you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you would like to use xBase, then it is much simpler if there is an index on January.A (lets say its tag is JanA - who would really name the fields A, B...) :

```
select February
replace all B with iif( seek(February.A, 'January', 'JanA'), 'Old', 'New')
```